# Setting image as Background

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i would like to ask why do i get error on this function. It loads all images from my directory but when I want to make it background onclick , I get error

```
var dir="uploads";
var fileextension = [".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg",".gif"];
$.ajax({
url: dir,
success: function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < fileextension.length; i++) {
    $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension[i] + ")").each(function () {
        var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http://", "");
        $("#backgroundSetting").append("<img src='" + dir + filename + "'onclick='imageBackground('" + dir + filename + "')'>");
    });
}
}
});
 function imageBackground(image){
 document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.backgroundImage ='url('+image+')';
}
```

Comment: What is the error  ?

Comment: If somebody gave you an answer as descriptive as your question, I think you'd be reasonably and justifiably upset. We need more information. What is the error?

Comment: That' my biggest problem error just go to my <!DOCTYPE html> , syntax error after i click one of my images

Comment: I think you are missing some quotes. Try `' onclick='imageBackground('" + dir + filename + "')'` instead.

Comment: now i am getting <!DOCTYPE html> , unexpected token , when i tried onclick='imageBackground('" + dir + filename + "')'

Comment: console.log (image); Did try this , getting error even on this so it's probably variable error but i just cant find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want your `dir + filename` treated as a variable in `imageBackground(" + dir + filename + ")` so you need to quote them.

Also  I changed your single quotes to double ones for readability...

```
$("#backgroundSetting").append("<img src=\"" + dir + filename + "\" onclick=\"imageBackground('" + dir + filename + "')\">");
```

Comment: Lol. Nice to sweet you.